# jQuery Выбор tr , если у него 50% td не пустые

Tags: javascript, jquery

Добрый день.

Подскажите, как написать правильное условие для selectorName: есть таблица, если в ней заполнено 50% информации, тогда красим в белый.

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
    var raws = $("[data-tr-classes=' realty-raw ']");
    $.each(raws, function (index, value) {
        if ($(value).parent().parent().find('сюда нужно вставить наш selectorName') {
            $(this).parent().parent().css('background-color', '#FFF');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: как определяется заполненность информацией?

Comment: if ($(value).parent().parent().find('td').text() !== ' ')
можно так, но как сделать условие, в котором если 50% td не пустые?

Comment: что значит _50% td не пустые?_?

Comment: ну тупо посчитать количество TD пустых в TR и высчитать процент по формуле, но тут не только селектор нужен, а еще например функция расчета процентного соотношения.

Comment: В проекте есть таблица выборки данных, с разными ролями: "сырые"  classes=' realty-raw ' красит в серый цвет и работает не совсем корректно, задача откорректировать в jQuery "сырые"-> если у этой tr(строки),  заполнено более 50% td перекрасить tr(всю строку) в белый цвет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задача решается в одну строку условия, без учета проверки деления на 0:

```
if($('td:empty').length / $('td').length >= 0.5) {
  // Тут ваше действие.
}
```

Селектор [`:empty`](http://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/) выбирает элементы, у которых нет дочерних нод, в том числе текстовых.

Answer (score 1):

Немного доработал через `:not(:empty)`

Функция находит строку (`tr`), считает количество не пустых элементов и если оно больше 50% красит в `#FFF`

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {

    var raws = $("[data-tr-classes=' realty-raw ']");

    $.each(raws, function (index, value) {

        if ($(value).parent().parent().find(('td:not(:empty)').length / $('td').length >= 0.5)) {

            $(this).parent().parent().css('background-color', '#FFF');
        }

    });

});
```